# how to fix mysql update some table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, mysqlupgrade

I update my version of mysql (->5.6) and now I lose some table, I think there are a pb with index table.
my process for update mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p
yum install wget -y
wget  http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-server
cd /var/lib/mysql
mv ib* /root
```

// erreur in this line --> mysql_upgrade -u root -p

Comment: ' I think there are a pb with index table' - translation please.

Comment: try explain better your question  .I can't understand what you wrote

Comment: He tried to update his m,ysql server abd after the update there are some tables missing. He also thinks it might be a indexing problem. So he gave us his update statement and asked why he gets an error

Comment: Please add the full error message you get from the mysql_upgrade client. And why do you run `mv ib* /root`? Why do you access the `/var/lib/mysql` directory anyway?

Comment: I use this tuto: https://www.it-connect.fr/installationupgrade-mysql-5-1-vers-5-6-sous-centos-6/ I think also there are a pb with index table but how to solve?

Comment: @user331157 What happens when you upgrade your mysql server based on the official upgrade documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/updating-yum-repo.html? What is the result you get when you do? You shouldn't mess around with mysql internal data structure unless you know what you do.

Comment: after updating the result -> mysql 56 is installed, when I make mysql_upgrade -u root -p, the result is Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.